# How to publish ASP.NET MVC on IIS server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-deployment

I am struggling with trying to publish a site.

I have made a basic web site with `ASP.NET` MVC and I now want to host it on a pc.

I have opened ISI manager and added a new site.  I set the default directly to the directly where the files for the site are stored but when i navigate to the pc I don't get my site. I get an `IIS` server error in application error.

What steps do i need to do to get the a basic site to run on the server.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-deploying-to-iis-as-a-test-environment-5-of-12

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have installed iis, this is done you have to register the asp.net framework, for this you need to run a command line.
Go to cmd and type:

> aspnet_regiis -i

Done so please enter

> http:// localhost/AplicationName

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error, then you should *really* post that error with your question. However, since the most common problem in the scenario you describe is permissions, I'm going to assume that that is your problem.

Unless you're going to put your code in a directory owned by IIS (such as "inetpub"), then you need to give the IIS user or group rights to the directory your code is in. You can do this by right-clicking the directory in Windows Explorer, and choosing "Properties". Then click the "Security" tab. Use the "Edit..." button to add the IIS user or group. It should be named something along the lines of "IIS_*". You'll need to grant full control, so just like any other publicly available directory (including "inetpub"), you should ensure that there's nothing secure or compromising in that directory.